# Api onedrive - Check the password of a onedrive shared directory

Tags: api, onedrive

I have a question about the onedrive api. I have a directory secured by password. Is there a way, via the api, to test the password? For exemple, use the api to connect to the url by submitting the password positioned on this directory and check if the access is ok?
Thank in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what API you are using exactly?